# Pass a single database entry from django to html template

Tags: python, html, django

Good Evening,

hope you all are healthy during this critical times!

I want to use the time to again work on my django web app.

This time in addition to showing all my customers on the page I want to return the information for a single customer, that I selected on the website.

I get the information about all the customers in the databse to show up on the website and when I use print in my views.py I see all the information from the single object.

However, it will not show up in my template :(

Here is my code (first the model):

```
class PrivateCustomer (models.Model):
WEIBLICH = 'W'
MANNLICH = 'M'
DIVERS = 'D'
KEINEANGABE = 'K'
GENDER =(
(WEIBLICH, 'Weiblich'),
(MANNLICH, 'Maennlich'),
(DIVERS, 'Divers'),
(KEINEANGABE, 'Keine Angabe')
)

kundennummer = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False, primary_key=True)
vorname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
nachname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
adresse = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
postleitzahl = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False)
stadt = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
geschlecht = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, choices=GENDER)
geburtstag = models.DateField(null=True)
telefon = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
mobil = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
datum = models.DateField(null=False)
 # def __str__(self):
 #   return self.nachname
```

Then the function in the views.py:

```
def showCustomer(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    kd = request.POST['kundennummer']
    customerSingle = PrivateCustomer.objects.filter(kundennummer=kd)
    form = PrivateCustomerForm()
    customers = PrivateCustomer.objects.all()
    print(type(customers[1]))
    print(type(customerSingle[0]))
    customerSingle = customerSingle[0]
    print(customerSingle.nachname)
    return render(request, 'basicERP/kunden.html', {'form' : form, 'customers' : customers, 'customerSingle' : customerSingle})
else:
    return HttpResponse("fail")
```

And my template code:

```
<div class="suchbereich">
        <div class="progress-table-wrap" id="suchtabelle">
            <div class="filterbereich">

            </div>
            <div class="progress-table" id="kundentabelle">
                <div class="table-head">
                    <button onclick="sortTable(0)" class="serial genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px; width:50px;">K-Nr.</button>
                    <button onclick="sortTable(1)" class="country genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px; width:150px;">Name</button>
                    <!--<button onclick="sortTable(2)" class="adresse genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">Adresse</button>
                    <button onclick="sortTable(3)" class="visit genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">Geschlecht</button>
                    <button onclick="sortTable(4)" class="visit genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">Geburtstag</button>
                    <button onclick="sortTable(5)" class="visit genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">Festnetz</button>
                    <button onclick="sortTable(6)" class="visit genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">Mobil</button>
                    <button onclick="sortTable(7)" class="email genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">E-Mail</button>-->
                    <div class="visit genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">Anzeigen</div>
                    <div class="visit genric-btn default circle" style="font-size:14px;">L&oumlschen</div>
                </div>
                    {% for customer in customers %}
                        <div class="table-row" onclick="setActive(this)">
                            <div class="serial" style="width:50px;">{{customer.kundennummer}}</div>
                            <div class="country" style="width:150px;">{{customer.nachname}}, {{customer.vorname}}</div>
                           <!-- <div class="adresse">{{customer.adresse}}, {{customer.postleitzahl}}, {{customer.stadt}}</div>
                            <div class="visit">{{customer.geschlecht}}</div>
                            <div class="visit">{{customer.geburtstag}}</div>
                            <div class="visit">{{customer.telefon}}</div>
                            <div class="visit">{{customer.mobil}}</div>
                            <div class="email">{{customer.email}}</div>-->
                           <button onclick="showCustomer(this)" class="genric-btn primary circle"> Anzeigen</button>
                            <button onclick="deleteCustomer(this)" class="genric-btn primary circle"> L&oumlschen</button>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="anzeigebereich">
            <div class="block1">
                <p>Adresse: {{customerSingle.nachname}}</p>{{customerSingle}}
                <p>PLZ, Ort: </p>{{customerSingle.postleitzahl}}, {{customerSingle.stadt}}
            </div>
            <div class="block2">

            </div>
            <div class="block3">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first table is filling fine, I can see all customers. When I call {{customerSingle.stadt}} I get nothing.

The output for the 3 print function calls in the views.py are:

```
<class 'erp.models.PrivateCustomer'>
<class 'erp.models.PrivateCustomer'>
Grünig
```

The third line is the last name of the specified object.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT

When I change my code in the views.py to this:

```
def showCustomer(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    kd = request.POST['kundennummer']
    customerSingle = PrivateCustomer.objects.filter(kundennummer=kd)
    form = PrivateCustomerForm()
    customers = PrivateCustomer.objects.all()
    customerSingle = customers.get(kundennummer=kd)
    #print(type(customers[1]))
    #print(type(customerSingle[0]))
    #customerSingle = customerSingle[0]
    mutti = 'hello'
    context = {
    #'form' : form,
    #'customers' : customers,
    #'customerSingle' : customerSingle,
    'dati': mutti
    }
    print(customerSingle.nachname)
    print('hallo')
    return render(request, 'basicERP/kunden.html', context)
else:
    return HttpResponse("fail")
```

The site is still getting rendered with the customer information, but the data 'hello' from the variable dati is not shown.

I added a second print() function to check that the right function is called. That is fine.

I don't understand how it can render correctly when I don't pass the customers variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine.

Have you tried stopping the server and restarting it?

When everything else fails, try changing something:

```
def showCustomer(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    kd = request.POST['kundennummer']
    form = PrivateCustomerForm()
    customers = PrivateCustomer.objects.all()
    customerSingle = customers.get(kundennummer=kd)
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'customers' : customers,
        'customerSingle' : customerSingle
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'basicERP/kunden.html', context)
else:
    return HttpResponse("fail")
```

Try checking if context what you are expecting.

Comment: Hi,

thank you for your reply. Yes I have restarted the server multiple times during the whole process (and just now I restarted it once again, unfortunately still with the same result).

I tried a different browser too now. Same result.

Comment: Thanks again, I edited my views.py in regard to your post. The list of customers still works fine (as well as the form), but still no information output for the {{customerSingle.nachname}}.

Am I referencing it wrong in html?